# change inline min-height with screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

in my website i am using a plugin which is by default sending inline min-height of iframe

```
<iframe id="ec-frame" allowfullscreen="" style="width: 100%;min-height:659px; height:100%;" src="https://dash.evercam.io/live.view.private.widget?camera=stephens-green&amp;refresh=1&amp;api_id=&amp;api_key=&amp;rtmp=rtmp://media.evercam.io:1935/live/stephens-green?token=qoSoGPwrzLlE0ITuMa2Id_VbCGRYYGAfGJlVZVm_LfA6fcVPcHqbymbJQ9uSMSOiyYtl24i4kHr4tIm_fxfadHVNVN8mxVQ_Xps9rGsIssc=&amp;hls=https://media.evercam.io/live/stephens-green/index.m3u8?token=qoSoGPwrzLlE0ITuMa2Id_VbCGRYYGAfGJlVZVm_LfA6fcVPcHqbymbJQ9uSMSOiyYtl24i4kHr4tIm_fxfadHVNVN8mxVQ_Xps9rGsIssc=" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

due to this, when screen width changes this min-height remains same and causing a lot of space between the iframe and lower div.

I am trying to change this with on resize function

```
var currentHeight = $("#test > iframe").css('min-height');
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      $('#test > iframe').css('min-height', "5px");
    });
```

but i really dont know/find how to edit this for dynamic min-height as screen width changes, the above function just set min-height to 5px but if i subtract something as

```
$('#test > iframe').css('min-height', currentHeight - "5px");
```

this doesn't work at all. what i want is to change min-height with the change in screen width as now min-height is at 659px, i want to subtract a value dynamically but dont know how to subtract it

Comment: you are subtracting `string` from `int`  `currentHeight - "5px"` . You have to do  `$('#test > iframe').css('min-height', parseInt(currentHeight) - 5);`

Comment: Put that in answer, i want to mark it as right ans.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subtracting `string` from `int` `currentHeight - "5px"` .

You have to do

```
 $('#test > iframe').css('min-height', parseInt(currentHeight) - 5);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its working awesome, parseInt was the thing which i want

Answer (score 0):

Hello change like this :

```
var currentHeight = $("#test > iframe").css('min-height');
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      $('#test > iframe').css('min-height', $( window ).height());
    });
```

that work dynamically as per how much you resize the window

thanks

Comment: this isnt what i asked